# Is it true that if $\sigma \in S_n,$ then $\sigma^n = \iota$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I think I remember my abstract algebra professor mentioning in class that if $\sigma$ is any permutation belonging to the symmetric group $S_n,$ then $\sigma^n = \iota,$ the identity permutation. Is this true, or can we just say that $\sigma^{n!} = \iota$?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Counter example?

Comment: Think about $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 5) \in S_{5}$.

Comment: $(12)\in S_3$.

Hell, you can use Cauchy's theorem to show it's **extremely** false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect, as Alastair's counterexample shows. Two related statements that *are* correct are:

- If $\sigma$ is an $n$-cycle (more generally, an $m$-cycle for $m | n$) then $\sigma^n = \iota$.
- For any finite group $G$, any element $g \in G$ satisfies $g^{\# G} = \iota$, and so for $\sigma \in S_n$, $\sigma^{n!} = 1$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining. How would you prove the second statement?

Comment: It's a consequence of Lagrange's Theorem, which says that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\# H | \# G$, which one can prove by counting cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: (And you're welcome, I'm glad you found my answer useful.)

Answer (score 0):

you rememmber wrong, consider $S_4$ and consider $\sigma =(1,2,3)$, then $\sigma^4=(1,2,3)=\sigma$.
I think, what your professor said was if $\sigma$ a $n$-cycle, then $\sigma^4=e$